# Would Pilots and Air travel be considered complementary?

Tags: microeconomics, supply-and-demand, demand

Now, my economics teacher and I have a disagreement. According to theory, as the price of air travel (airline tickets) increases, the demand for pilots will decrease as well because fewer people will be willing and able to buy the same airline ticket with an increased price, this should result in a fall of quantity demanded of airplanes and thus fewer pilots will be required/demanded. Thus, an increase in the price of air travel results in a decrease of demand for pilots. Thus, pilots and air travel are complimentary. My teacher thinks that pilots and air travel are not complimentary. Can anyone confirm my logic and economic claims?

Answer (score 1):

Consumers buy airline tickets but don't hire pilots, so I wouldn't call those two complementary in the usual sense of "complementary goods".